# Class references null when starting service in background

Tags: java, android, service, kryonet

I am trying to implement a "never-ending background service" in my android app. It should be used to wait for a server sending a certain type of object to the client and notify the user when this happens. As a template I use [fabcirablog](https://fabcirablog.weebly.com/blog/creating-a-never-ending-background-service-in-android#).
When I try to start the Service with an intent the references I have to use in onStartCommand these refs appear to be null.

I tried setting the variables one by one in the Service-constructor and fetch them in onStartCommand itself. Every time they result in nullreferences.

## MainActivity:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
    super.onCreate(bundle);

    ...

    if (clientHandler == null)
        clientHandler = new ClientHandler(this, this);

    if (clientService == null) {
        clientService = new ClientService(this, this);
        mServiceIntent = new Intent(this, clientService.getClass());

        if (!isMyServiceRunning(clientService.getClass()))
            startService(mServiceIntent);                            //somehow creates a new ClientService instance with null variables such as mainActivity, clientHandlder...
    }
}
```

## Service:

### Constructor:

```
public ClientService(Context applicationContext, MainActivity mainActivity) {
    super();

    this.mainActivity = mainActivity;
    client = mainActivity.getClient();
}
```

### onStartCommand:

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);

    client.addListener(new Listener(){              //FIXME client is null (a mainActivity would be null too)
        @Override
        public void connected(Connection connection) {
            super.connected(connection);
        }

        @Override
        public void disconnected(Connection connection) {
            super.disconnected(connection);
        }

        @Override
        public void received(Connection connection, Object o) {
            Log.i("SERVICE", "Received: " + o.toString());
        }
    });

    client.start();
    Network.register(client);

    return START_STICKY;
}
```

## Error log:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start service com.simplecodings.smma.tools.ClientService@b6efbc2 with Intent { cmp=com.simplecodings.smma/.tools.ClientService }: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.esotericsoftware.kryonet.Client.addListener(com.esotericsoftware.kryonet.Listener)' on a null object reference
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:3343)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap21(ActivityThread.java)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1582)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.esotericsoftware.kryonet.Client.addListener(com.esotericsoftware.kryonet.Listener)' on a null object reference
    at com.simplecodings.smma.tools.ClientService.onStartCommand(ClientService.java:50)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:3326)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap21(ActivityThread.java) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1582) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

Can I, e.g. reference the client / mainActivity by passing them via .putExtra?

Comment: *am trying to implement a "never-ending background service"*  I didn't read past the first paragraph of your question but this is simple not possible. The app should not monitor the server. The server should notify the app.

Comment: @Tim Castelijns I updated my question to its true behaviour. Instead of monitoring it is waiting for an object

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Read [this](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services) and implement a bound service using the method "Extending the Binder class". The way you are trying to communicate between your `Activity` and your `Service` is incorrect.

Having a never-ending background service is also [not possible](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background.html). You might get away with using a foreground service. You should consider not monitoring your server in a `Service`, but instead use push messages like Firebase Cloud Messaging to notify your app when something happens in your server.

Answer (score 1):

Your Activity/Service class members like `this.mainActivity` or `this.client` are null because android may have decided to kill and recreate Activity/Service (i.e. if you rotate the device) therefore those member are either null or pointing to already destoyed Activities/Services